# Git Project with Multi-Product Flavor and Dimension

Tags: android, git, version-control, android-productflavors, android-flavordimension

Could anyone please guide me on how to correctly apply git to an Android Project with multiple Product Flavor and Dimension.

I could simple add a Git to the whole project but would that be the right way to do it?

EDIT:

Lets say I'm building a Store Application.

I would have the following configuration

flavorDimensions "client", "network"
  productFlavors {
    client1 {
      dimension "client"
      ...
    }

```
client2 {
  dimension "client"
  ...
}

prod {
  dimension "network"
  ...
}

debug {
  dimension "network"
  ...
}
```

}

The result product flavors would be sharing a same "Code Base" (since they are both a Store Application) but they would also need to have individual Iteration/Version releases/features.

One way I think about doing this (and the only way I know doing it) is to simply add the Git to the whole project. Create a branch for the product flavor and go on from there. Only problem is when i do some changes to the "Base Code" I would have to cascade it to some if not all of the branches.

My question is if this is the correct way of doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on how your project is having different flavors and dimensions. I think sharing more details on flavors and dimensions would help you in getting answers!

Comment: @PareshMayani - I've edited my question with an example. Please help me with your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any of below options:

#### Option1: manage all projects in the same branch and tag for different projects versions

Assume you manage 2 projects in the same branch, you can use tags to assist to manage different projects versions separately: version format `A*.*.*` (such as `A1.0.0`) for project1 and version format `B*.*.*` (such as `B1.0.0`) for project2.

To add a tag for HEAD:

```
git tag -a <version> -m 'message'
```

To add a tag for a history commit:

```
git tag -a <version> -m 'message' <commit>
```

#### Option2: manage different projects in separate branches

You can manage each project in different branches so that you can manage and track the versions for different projects separately.

And if the "code base" changes in one branch, you can apply the changes into other branches.

To apply a file from a branch (such as `branchA`) to another branch (such as `branchB`), you can use below commands:

```
git checkout branchB
git checkout branchA -- filename
git commit -m 'apply the changes of the filename from branchA into branchB'
```

Comment: this is the first time I've heard the use of tags and honestly, I don't quite understand the first option well enough yet. I'd probably go and study it first. Could you give me a short description of what tags are? Does option 1 also means that I'd be managing the two project at the same time meaning both must have the same version?

Comment: Tags in git can helps you to record certains commits which are import to your process. And you can treat a tag is short for a commit. More details about tagging, you can refer https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging.

Comment: @ArchieQuiñones Have you solved the problem now? If yes, you can mark it as answer (√ symbol on the left on the answer). And it will also benefit others who have similar questions.

Comment: Hi Marina, I'm sorry haven't gotten the time to check on this yet. That is why I haven't marked it as an Answer yet. I'll be checking on it this weekend. Your answer got me somewhere to start. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Ok, you can have a try later. And if there has anything sticks, feel free let me know :)

Comment: I don't think Option 1 was good for my scenario as I would imagine maintaining a seperate branch for each Product Flavor. Option 2 seems to be a better option.

Comment: My additional question is, is it possible to not have the files not related to the Product Flavor to a branch? For example, I have client1 and client2 product flavors. I want to have a branchClient1 where it only contains the BaseCode and the Client1 Specific Files and a branchClient2 where it also only contains the BaseCode and the Client2 Specific files. I would want something like this so I would not need to see unnecessary files when maintaining for specific Product Flavor. Is this possible?

Comment: That's co-use the BaseCode for two branches. And yes, it's possible. You can just to "copy" the BaseCode from a branch to the other (just as the three commands in option2 do the same thing).

Comment: That's good news then. I'd go and try setup Option 2. I may still have questions during or after it. I hope you'd still be there to answer. You've been a really big help. Thank you very much. :)